# Flutter : Run an app as a background service

Tags: flutter

I want to show a custom popup message whenever the user disconnects a cellular call. The problem is how to detect when the app is not running. any leads would be helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3671#issuecomment-404237222 This is work in progress. I don't know if there is currently a working solution.

Comment: to show a popup from background, try this https://pub.dev/packages/system_alert_window

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been a while and there have been many developments.

First, there are some answers at [How to create a service in Flutter to make an app to run always in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106844/how-to-create-a-service-in-flutter-to-make-an-app-to-run-always-in-background)

Also, [flutter/Background processes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) will basically point you to [medium/Executing Dart in the Background with Flutter Plugins and Geofencing](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) (Sept 2018)

- which is a [Geofencing sample](https://github.com/bkonyi/FlutterGeofencing) that involves a partnership between [isolates](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html), native Android/iOS code via `MethodChannel`, and `PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle` ([PluginUtilities](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PluginUtilities-class.html))

Alas, there are many plugins available now:

- https://pub.dev/packages/background_location
- https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager (Android)
- https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch
- https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager
- https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to get my app to run in the background for quite a while now but couldnt find a solution that fit my needs. However i have finally found something that I thought might benefit others looking for a solution. The workmanager package has an unpublished branch that provides the ability to run background code on ios upon closing the app. There seem to be little limitations except a time limit. find the pull request here:

- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/pull/511
  (This contains important information on breaking changes that are on this branch)

and the branch here:

- https://github.com/absar/flutter_workmanager/tree/ios-bg-tasks-enh-final