# Is it possible to make a background service in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, background

I'm building an app that receives GPS signals every five seconds, and I know that these background service apps shut down on their own.

1. If background service is not available on Android OS, how does it work a service like Uber?
2. I heard the Programmer can register a whitelist that doesn't automatically close even if the app resides in the background. How can I register whitelist?

Comment: this link might help https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Comment: thanks for your reply, Rather than the official method, I'm looking for a way to make a detour it.

Comment: re [flutter] tag: you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/59057145/6668797 for some ways

Answer (score 0):

I am make a background servcie in flutter like this way right now:

```
/// The entry of dart background service
/// NOTE: this method will be invoked by native (Android/iOS)
/// avoid Tree Shaking
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void playerBackgroundService() {
  CommonUtils.initialApp(ConfigType.PRO).whenComplete(() => {
    loadRepository()
  });
}

void loadRepository() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  GlobalConfig.init(ConfigType.PRO);
  netRepository = Repository();
  runBackgroundService(
    imageLoadInterceptor: BackgroundInterceptors.loadImageInterceptor,
  );
}
```

hop this help for you.