# Flutter Always Background Service

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

**Hi,**

*I need a help in background service which should work like messaging apps even if app was closed.
I am doing project for tracking for every 15 min and also notification building. I am not getting like how to do it i have tried background_fetch but i am not clear with it. Can you please suggest me the way or with any good pub suggestion to solve my problem.*

**Thank you.**

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59057145/6668797 for some other ways