# Run background service at device boot

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-process

I want to create a background service in my app which will be started at device boot. I read some questions here on SO, but I didn't find a good solution.

I'm thinking to WhatsApp, which runs a background service to check if there are new messages, also with app closed or not yet opened (from boot).

I want to write code only once for both android and ios. In this background service, I need to check if there are new contents (every 5 minutes do a http request) and if firebase sends a cloud message to create a notification in the app.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539893/flutter-run-an-app-as-a-background-service/59057145) and those linked, but I would to have here in this question the complete step-by-step guide to do what I want.

Now, in my app, I have only ChangeNotifierProvider and Consumer to fetch http data and place them in the widgets. I think that in background process I can run ChangeNotifier subfunctions.

What you advice?

Comment: Many manufacturers has advanced optimizations, which stops apps from running in background. To tackle that, you can use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/disable_battery_optimization

Answer (score 0):

You can try with two plugins.

- [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch).
- [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager).

Comment: As far as I can tell, neither of those handles starting automatically on boot.

Comment: background_fetch: "Unlike iOS, the Android implementation can continue to operate after application terminate (stopOnTerminate: false) or device reboot (startOnBoot: true)."