# How to run app Flutter background service in closed stated?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is it possible for an application written with Flutter to run continuously with service written in the background in closed stated ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59057145/6668797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes is possible** there several packages like:

> https://pub.dev/packages/background_location
>
> https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager (Android)
>
> https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch
>
> https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

But if you wanna **more control** you can create a native service and connect it with flutter to do that you have to know android languages like java or kotlin or swift for iphone

In this post you can find how to create a service in android:

[How to create a service in Flutter to make an app to run always in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106844/how-to-create-a-service-in-flutter-to-make-an-app-to-run-always-in-background)