# Receiving call same as WhatsApp in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing a video call feature in Flutter with the help of Firebase Cloud Messaging,
it's working fine in foreground.

my doubt is
while app is in background I need to get a receiving call same like as WhatsApp in both Android and IOS .... is it possible in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

yes. it is possible by the combination of [push notification](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)  and [flutter_callkeep](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkeep) to show the upcoming call screen.

Or if you want to run the background process you need to refer to [Method Channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels), and here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106844/how-to-create-a-service-in-flutter-to-make-an-app-to-run-always-in-background) about creating a service for running app in the background. also [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch)  is a useful package for background process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..... I will check and let you know