# How to get real time update in a Flutter app when the app is in background?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

In my flutter app, I need to update the location of the mobile user every 10 seconds, even if the app is not active (terminated).

How do I achieve this?

I have gone through [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) and [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)

Both have bugs and don't fulfill my need as they follow OS criteria of getting executed periodically every 15 minutes minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Right now in flutter is not easy to do that. what i did was write code in android and comunicate con dart code using **methodChannel**, here is the post that i followed:
[How to create a service in Flutter to make an app to run always in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106844/how-to-create-a-service-in-flutter-to-make-an-app-to-run-always-in-background)